# Notion API: how to get the URL of uploaded files

Tags: notion-api

I'm using the Notion API Beta, reading pages from a table that has a "Files & media" property I'm interested in. The API response just gives me the names of the files uploaded there, but I don't have a URL to actually access them. What am I missing? Thanks.

```json
{
  "Photo": {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "type": "files",
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "000150748673-ofnuhb-t500x500.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update:** see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69280377/995958).

---

Comment: Do they expect you to prepend your workspace URL?  I don’t know how to get it programmatically but you could probably hardcode a string for testing.

Comment: @prieber Where did you get that info? It looks it's not working, it says `{ "message": "File not found" }`

Comment: Oh I just made that up, I haven’t used the API yet but thought that might be a good place to start.

Comment: You can't at the moment. The URL of the uploaded files is presigned when you try to download them. You'll notice they point to a URL that has secure.notion-static.com inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Notion API currently does not support file uploads or downloads (Notion-Version: 2021-05-13). It does not return a URL to the stored file.

Answer (score 4):

The API has been updated and [it now provides a temporary authenticated URL to files uploaded in Notion](https://developers.notion.com/reference/file-object). For example:

```json
{
  "Photo": {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "type": "files",
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "000150748673-ofnuhb-t500x500.jpg",
        "type": "file",
        "file": {
          "url": "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/...",
          "expiry_time": "2021-09-22T09:00:56.029Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```